# What does Islam says about e.g. relatives who ask for money but don't work despite being healthy?

Tags: work, family

I have relatives who are healthy enough to work a job. But they don't. All they do is stay at home.  They are married and have children too.

They always ask me for money because I am earning very good money from my Software Engineering job.

What should I tell them? Should I give them money?

Comment: Think what it teaches them if you do. Other than that, this seems pretty specific., can you edit it to make it less about your particular situation and applicable to a slightly more general case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a personal advice question.

Answer (score 1):

If I am instead of you, at first I know him, Is he lazy or he can not find a good job. If he is lazy and never try to find job, its clear, do not help him because he does not like to improve him self.
If he likes to find job but he can not, help him to find job( we have adage: don't give him a fish, learn him fishing).
I do these .

Comment: As i told they are 100%fit and are able to work. But they dont want to work, they always keep looking at someone else's money

Comment: try to talk them and said them these behavior is not good.